# Random Cat Generator Using API discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm attempting to generate a random cat image and put it into an embed using discord.py, but I'm getting an error. Here's my code:

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os
import keep_alive
import asyncio
import json
import io
import contextlib
import datetime


async def get(session: object, url: object) -> object:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


class Image(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command()
    async def cat(ctx, self):
      response = requests.get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
      data = response.json()
      embed = discord.Embed(
          title = 'Kitty Cat ',
          description = 'Cats :star_struck:',
          colour = discord.Colour.purple()
          )
      embed.set_image(url=data['file'])            
      embed.set_footer(text="")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Image(bot))
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'send'
```

How do I get the embed to send with the image?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are interested this is how I added it to my bot.

```
from typing import Text
import discord
import aiohttp

@client.command(help = "It shows you a cat photo as well as a fact")
async def cat(ctx):
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      request = await session.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/cat')
      dogjson = await request.json()
      # This time we'll get the fact request as well!
      request2 = await session.get('https://some-random-api.ml/facts/cat')
      factjson = await request2.json()
```

I am using the random API

Answer (score 0):

In method arguments, `self` must goes first.
self is defining object itself: you're calling Image object as ctx name.

Solution:

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os
import keep_alive
import asyncio
import json
import io
import contextlib
import datetime


async def get(session: object, url: object) -> object:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


class Image(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def cat(self, ctx):
      response = requests.get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
      data = response.json()
      embed = discord.Embed(
          title = 'Kitty Cat ',
          description = 'Cats :star_struck:',
          colour = discord.Colour.purple()
          )
      embed.set_image(url=data['file'])            
      embed.set_footer(text="")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Image(bot))
```